# Does usage of COSMOS data migration tool consuming any RUs?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does usage of COSMOS data migration tool for periodical backups (export data to blob storage and then restore it when needed) consuming any RUs ? And does it affect performance or availability of my db operations? 
What is recommended solution to implement in COSMOS smth like snapshots for blobs in az storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does usage of COSMOS data migration tool for periodical backups
>   (export data to blob storage and then restore it when needed)
>   consuming any RUs?

Yes. Because you're reading from your Cosmos DB collections you will consume RUs.

> And does it affect performance or availability of my db operations?

Again, Yes. Simply because you have assigned certain RUs for your collection and taking a backup is consuming a part of those RUs effectively leaving you with lesser RUs for other operations.

> What is recommended solution to implement in COSMOS smth like
>   snapshots for blobs in az storage?

I'm also curious to know about this. Just thinking out loud, one possible solution would be to increase the throughput (i.e. either assign more RUs or enable RUPM) when backup is going on so that other operations are not impacted and bring them back to normal once backup is done.

Comment: You mentioned RU/minute. That doesn't exist anymore, FYI.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Thanks! RUPM is gone? When did this happen? Looks like I missed on the announcement. Can you share a link which talks about this?

Answer (score 0):

Any operation against Cosmos DB is going to consume RU (that is, each operation has an RU cost). If you're reading content to back up to another source, it's still going to cost you RU during the reads.

As for affecting performance of other db operations: depends on your RU capacity. If you exceed your committed capacity, then you're throttled. If you find yourself being throttled while backing up, you'll need to increase RU accordingly.

There is no "best" solution for backup. Up to you.